# Can a foreign key column be an Enum in Entity Framework 6 code first?

Tags: c#, enums, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

I am converting EF5 DB first into EF6 code first. in the old setup there are some FKs that are bytes. and in the application are mapped to enums with the underlining type of byte. this has been working wonderfully.

Going over to code first and EF6 I found claims that enums should "just work" and indeed that seems to be the case for regular columns. I can just go from this

```
public byte FavPersonality {get;set;}
```

to this:

```
public Personality FavPersonality {get;set;}
```

but when it comes to columns that are also foreign keys I get this error :

```
System.ArgumentException : The ResultType of the specified expression is not
compatible with the required type. The expression ResultType is 'Edm.Byte'
but the required type is 'Model.Personality'.
```

Is this something that cannot be done with EF6 + Code first?

edit:

enum is defined as :byte

Comment: Is your enum defined with " : byte" after the name?

Answer (score 19):

I just ran into this same issue with my enum being a basic number enum, but this came up as the first result in the search by message. I had a subtype on my main object where the values were of a fixed set of values. But, there were also objects for those so we could write queries against them.

```
public class Foo {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BarEnum BarId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BarId))]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public enum BarEnum {
    Type1,
    Type2
}
```

This configuration gave me the same error message as described in this question:

> The ResultType of the specified expression is not
>   compatible with the required type. The expression ResultType is 'BarEnum'
>   but the required type is 'Edm.Int'.

The resolution for this was simple: Just change the Id of `Bar` to use the enum as well, and everything worked without a problem. This does make sense, as there are **far** more values possible for an `int` than there are for a `BarEnum`.

```
public class Bar {
    [Key]
    public BarEnum Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Been a while and my code is long gone, if someone can confirm that this answers the question i'll mark it.

Comment: Not a problem. Like I said, this was top result when I searched for the error text. Hunting down all the places where Foreign Keys were being used was a chore, but once I did, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** - As per [@krillgars answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995394), in modern EF it's better to just use the actual enum type as the Primary Key (and referenced Foreign Keys) - EF6 and EfCore can map this out fine.

**Old Answer**

I also got the error:

> The ResultType is `MyEnum` of the specified expression is not compatible with the required type 'Edm.Int32'. Parameter name: keyValues[0]

When using the enumeration mapping:

```
[Column("MyActualFKColumnId", TypeName = "int")]
public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }

// NB : Foreign Key refers to the C# Property, not the DB Field
[ForeignKey("MyEnum")]
public MyEntityReferencedByEnum MyEntityReferencedByEnum { get; set; }
```

However, I was able to work around the above by reinstating the original integer foreign key (`MyActualFKColumnId`), removing the `[Column]` and `[ForeignKey]` attributes, and then adding a `[NotMapped]` property hack to the class:

```
[NotMapped]
public MyEnum MyEnum
{
    get { return (MyEnum) MyActualFKColumnId; }
    set { MyActualFKColumnId=(int)value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error when the PK's doesn't match the FK's to a child entity. For example, when using a composite PK whose column order doesn't match the FK's. Like this:

```
class Foo
{
    [Key, Column(Order=10)]
    int Pk1 {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(Order=20)]
    short Pk2 {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Pk2,Pk1")] // <== ORDER DOESN'T MATCH PK OF CHILD ENTITY
    Foo Child {get;set;}
}
```

With the above code, EF will try to join table `Foos` with itself, but with criss-crossed columns, so their types won't match.